# hook into Rails built-in remote: true 'ajax:success' event

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

For a few weeks I have been avoiding the Rails UJS "Ajax helpers" provided by rails.js and `remote: true`. As a result, I was doing something like this:

```
// erb
<li>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span><%= tagging.tag.name %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :id, tagging.id %>
  </button>
</li>

// js
    remove_tag: function(){
        $view.on('click','.cloud .glyphicon-remove', function(){  
            var id = $(this).next().val();              
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: {id: id},
                url: 'taggings/destroy',
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $('.loading').show();
                },
                complete: function(){
                    $('.loading').hide();
                },
                success: function(resp){
                   alert( resp );
                }
            });
        })
    },
```

But it was obviously a lot of work to do this over and over. So I decided using `remote: true` and rails.js built-in unobtrusive features was more elegant:

```
 <li>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md">
    <%= link_to tagging, remote: true, method: :delete, class: 'remove-tag' do %>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <% end %>
    <%= tagging.tag.name %>
  </button>
</li>
```

Which translates into this nice code:

```
<li>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md">
    <a class= "remove-tag" data-method="delete" data-remote="true" href="/taggings/1" rel="nofollow">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </a>
    orange
  </button>
</li>
```

Now I can invoke the beforeSend and complete but the success ajax event is not triggered. I followed the suggestion of [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#button-to) link. However, the 'ajax:success' is not being called:

```
 remove_tag: function(){
        $view.on('ajax:beforeSend', '.cloud .remove-tag', function(event, xhr, settings) {
            $('.loading').show();
        })

        $view.on('ajax:complete', '.cloud .remove-tag', function(event, xhr, settings) {
            $('.loading').hide();
        })

        $view.on('ajax:success', '.cloud .remove-tag', function(event, xhr, settings) {
            alert("It was a success!")
        })
    },
```

How can I invoke 'ajax:success' event?

Comment: It seems that only if you modify, such as delete, the record rails will invoke the success event. So some flag must be passed back to the client.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out the problem. My goal was to remove the unnecessary use of something like this:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     data: $form.serialize(),
     url: $form.attr('action'),
     beforeSend: function() {
       $('.loading').show();
     },
     complete: function(){
       $('.loading').hide();
       $form.closest('.modal').modal('hide')
     },
     success: function(resp){
       console.log(resp);
     }
});
```

And by using the `remote: true` on the link, the Rails `link_to` helper generates a `data-remote` attribute, which the rails.js file will add an event listener to for ajax requests, therefore removing the need for the jquery `$.ajax()` method.

What I did not realize was that, the ajax call BY DEFAULT sets the dataType to 'script' and therefore the HTTP Request Headers `Accept` header is set with 'application/javascript'. Thus, the content type in the response will be `:js` (application/javascript). This requires you to either define a `:action.js.erb` file or pass a block. But if you pass a block, it will be a block evaluated as JavaScript, not JSON or TEXT! Hence, when I was sending JSON back to the browser, it got confused. It was expecting to evaluate javascript, not parse JSON and thus a parse error would occur.

```
$view.on('ajax:beforeSend', '.cloud .remove-tag', function(xhr, settings) {
    $('.loading').show();
})

$view.on('ajax:complete', '.cloud .remove-tag', function(xhr, status) {
    $('.loading').hide();
})

// this only triggered if you actually destroy record
$view.on('ajax:success', '.cloud .remove-tag', function(data, status, xhr) {
    $('.loading').hide();

    // JSON.parse not needed; status already parsed as json
    var data_id = JSON.parse(status['data-id']);
    $('.cloud').find("li[data-id='"+data_id['data-id']+"']").remove();
            })
$view.on('ajax:error', '.cloud .remove-tag', function(xhr, status, error) {
   console.log( error );
})
```

Consequently, `ajax:error` was being triggered and not `ajax:success`. 
When I changed the link to specify I wanted json as a response, then `ajax:success` was triggered.

```
<%= link_to tagging, remote: true, method: :delete, class: 'remove-tag', :'data-type' => 'json' do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<% end %>
```

So why did I choose to return JSON and not just use `format.js` and add a `delete.js.erb` file? Because that means I would have to reference a DOM id or class in that js.erb file because I would have lost context to the module I created. By passing the data back to the event listener, I was able to continue to work with the closure created by the javascript functions.

Comment: Really helpful over a year later!

Answer (score 1):

I do not know, whats your `$view` is, but example in below should be handle it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //form id
    $('.remove-tag')
    .bind('ajax:success', function(evt, data, status, xhr) {
      //function called on status: 200 (for ex.)
      console.log('success');
      alert("It was a success!");
    })
    .bind("ajax:error", function(evt, xhr, status, error) {
      //function called on status: 401 or 500 (for ex.)
      console.log(xhr.responseText);
    });
  });
```

You have also 2nd option to handle it, just creating `destroy.js.erb` file.

```
console.log("Coupon | destroy.js.erb file");

$('nav').after("<div class='alert alert-danger'> Successfully Destroyed </div>");
$(".coupon_" + <%= @coupon.id %>).fadeOut(250, function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: The success appeared to be called ONLY when I actually deleted the record. If I did not delete a record, and still passed data back to the view like {success: true}, the success action was not called.

Comment: When you use remote: true, is format.js the format it expects?

Comment: that 2nd option, works only after destroy success calls file. if deleting not success it will not be called. EDITED: also when doing `remote: true` it will run all behind scene no refresh no nothing, just will delete from DB. Try yrself to delete any DATA and refresh yr page right now, you ll see, asynchronously will delete for you.

Comment: I have this in my controller: format.js { render text: { 'data-id' => id }.to_json } and for some reason, 'ajax:success' is not invoked now. Even when I do delete the item. delete.js.erb works, but I want to send data back to the client script. I do not want to render delete.js.erb

Comment: why r u doing `render text: {}.to_json` ? also if you dnt like railsy way, then write yr own `$.ajax` handle it as json and respond with json. also 1st option works on forms actually.

Comment: I am using render text: {}.to_json because I want to send data to 'ajax:success' since it is in a module. If used destroy.js.erb, I would have to reference dom elements on page by id or class or something else.

Comment: I figured out the problem and posted the answer. Although I give this +1 for the help.

Comment: @7urkm3n thank you very much. I do have a problem. I"m adding the $('.remove-tag') elements upon an event, AFTER the page has uploaded - in fact. how can i add the AJAX success event to these elements which are added to the page after it has been loaded? any advice much appreciated.

Comment: @BKSpurgeon what do u mean by "the page after it has been loaded?" ? can you describe it ? i didnt get it )))

Comment: @7urkm3n ok so the page comes up. The user is having a good time. Then the user clicks a drop down menu and I then display a table created using Ajax and JQuery. I want to add AJAX success events to the elements which are added dynamically through Jquery, well after the page has been loaded - because those elements were created on the fly as a result of another event (e.g. the user clicking a drop down menu). I hope that makes sense?